# How to determine (in AS3) whether the system cursor is hidden or showing?

Tags: actionscript-3, mouse-cursor

We have two methods to handle cursor visibility in action script 3: Mouse.hide() and .show().

My movie loads an external one, that may intentionally hide cursor. And I have to change interface depending on it's decision.

Can I detect whether it's hidden or showing? And how?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Mouse.html)  there doesn't appear to be a property representing visibility of the `Mouse`. This means that what you may need to do is dispatch events from the externally loaded SWF when you `.show()` and `.hide()` the mouse, and then listen for those events in the top level to trigger the appropriate reactions.